# How to save a Dataframe into an excel sheet without deleting the other sheets?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I've seen other responses but I don't think they work for my specific issue.

I have an excel sheet with 3 sheets.

first sheet has

```
Name             Dept           
John Smith       candy       
Diana Princ      candy       
Tyler Perry      candy       
Perry Plat       wood       
Jerry Springer   clothes     
Calvin Klein     clothes     
Mary Poppins     clothes     
Ivan Evans       clothes     
Lincoln Tun      warehouse   
Oliver Twist     kitchen     
Herman Sherman   kitchen
```

second sheet is:

```
Depts Responded
candy
wood
clothes
warehouse
kitchen
```

Third sheet is:

```
Depts Not Responded
chocolate
vanilla
computers
```

I want to update my spreadsheet with Python, such as adding chocolate to the Depts Responded sheet.
So far my code is like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import os, csv, sys

excel_data = 'file.xlsx'

responded = ['candy', 'wood', 'clothes', 'warehouse', 'kitchen','chocolate']
not_responded = ['vanilla', 'computers']

test_nr = pd.DataFrame(not_responded)
test_r = pd.DataFrame(responded)

test_r = notemp_df.rename({0: 'Depts Responded'}, axis=1)
test_nr = empty_df.rename({0: 'Depts Not Responded'}, axis=1)

test_nr = test_nr.reset_index(drop=True)
test_r = test_r.reset_index(drop=True)

# create excel writer object
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_data)
test_nr.to_excel(writer, 'Departments Not Responded')
test_r.to_excel(writer, 'Departments Responded')

# save the excel file
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

But when I run this, it deletes the first sheet, and only writes the second and third sheet like this:

```
Depts Responded
0 candy
1 wood
2 clothes
3 warehouse
4 kitchen
5 chocolate

Depts Not Responded
0 vanilla
1 computers
```

So that part is working, but I'm losing the first sheet.
Is there a way to only edit those sheets and not erase the first one?
And also removed the index numbers of the new data.

---

Thanks to one of the responses below by Redox, I dug more into openpyxl and found an answer that worked for me. As the data is just an example based off my real data. Here is my working code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os, csv, sys

def delete(sheet):
    while(sheet.max_row > 1):
        sheet.delete_rows(2)
    return

excel_data = 'file.xlsx'

responded = ['candy', 'wood', 'clothes', 'warehouse', 'kitchen','chocolate']
not_responded = ['vanilla', 'computers']

test_nr = pd.DataFrame(not_responded)
test_r = pd.DataFrame(responded)

test_r = notemp_df.rename({0: 'Depts Responded'}, axis=1)
test_nr = empty_df.rename({0: 'Depts Not Responded'}, axis=1)

test_nr = test_nr.reset_index(drop=True)
test_r = test_r.reset_index(drop=True)

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_data)
ws = workbook['Depts Not Responded'] # Go to the required worksheet
delete(ws)

max1 = ws.max_row
for row, entry in enumerate(not_responded, start=1):
   ws.cell(row=row+max1, column=1, value=entry)

workbook.save('output.xlsx') #Save it back

wt = workbook['Depts Responded'] # Go to the required worksheet
delete(wt)

max2 = wt.max_row
for row, entry in enumerate(responded, start=1):
   wt.cell(row=row+max2, column=1, value=entry)

workbook.save('output.xlsx') #Save it back
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is add a new entry(row) to an existing sheet, the simplest and correct way would be to open the existing file, get to the right worksheet/tab, get to the last row with data and add the row to the row below that. With opwnpyxl.load_workbook(), you can do that.

As you might be adding entries on a daily basis, it is not a good idea to have all the data in the python list and rewrite the same each time. Your code is actually creating new tabs with all the data from scratch each time you run it.

In the below example, I have the file you mentioned (filex.xlsx) with 3 worksheets (Sheet1/2/3) and the data as per the question. The below code will open this workbook and append 'chocolate' to Sheet2 at the bottom of the list. It will NOT remove/replace any existing data.

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx') #Open the file
ws = workbook['Sheet2']   # Go to the required worksheet
ws.cell(row=ws.max_row+1, column=1).value = 'chocolate' #Add the value to cell - max_row is the last row with data in it....
workbook.save('output.xlsx') #Save it back
```

**Output after running above code**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This didn't exactly give me the answer, but it opened me up more to openpyxl, which lead me to figuring out the answer :) I'll update my question with the answer above.